# nasm: ELF format cannot produce non-PC-relative PLT references

Tags: nasm

I'm experiencing an error with `nasm` compiler. Inside nasm's source code the error originates [here](https://github.com/letolabs/nasm/blob/master/output/outelf64.c#L874).

I' trying to build an relocatable object file that can resolve a specific symbol during run time linkage (not build time linkage).

Minimal code:

```
EXTERN start

foo:
    ; wrt: with respect to 
    dd start wrt ..plt
```

The error is **ELF format cannot produce non-PC-relative PLT references**.
What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have to use `dd start wrt ..got`, i.e. reference the *global offset table* instead of the *procedure linkage table*. The latter would only work with something like `call start wrt ..plt`, i.e. an real instruction. In this case you are using `dd`, i.e. storing an immediate value in the output.